# Why to use the entire DLR in own Script-Engine

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, scripting, dynamic-language-runtime

I've build my own script engine and im an at the point, that the code is parsed into a nice tree. Now i am facing the problem, that i need to "execute" the tree in my own runtime. That is no problem at all, but i am not sure how and which tools i should use.

I have read a lot of the [DLR-Specs](https://dlr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Docs%20and%20specs&referringTitle=Home) but i am not sure, why to use it. I think that i can handle every thing with the [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why should i use things like ScriptRuntime, ScriptEngine, ScriptScope from the DLR? I have implemented my completely own parsing and executing algorithm.

Here is my current project-structure:
[image]

Comment: There is no code, it is a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the dlr for that was a good choise, because it's provide all functionality neeed. First started with writing my own stuff, but ended up with using the dlr.